# 衰落：decadence or decline?

Tags: word-choice, word-requests

I'm trying to describe the plot of the work 红楼梦 using the phrase "the 贾 family's decline". The word for decline, though is confusing me. After putting "decline" through a few online translators, I've received the word 衰落. But when I reverse the translation to check it, sometimes I get decline and sometimes decadence, which is not what I'm trying to say. Is there a more appropriate word in this context to say decline without the implication of decadence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The phrase you are looking for is "come/go down in the world", meaning to lose wealth or high social rank in one's past. It can be translated to Chinese as "家道中落".

Answer (score 2):

> The term 'decadence' should be translated as '沈溺與腐化' (indulge and corrupt)

~

> The term 'decline' should be translated as  **衰落 (decline/ descend)**; 衰退 (decline/ recede); 減弱 (decline/ weakening); 減少 (decline/ decrease)

I don't think translating '衰落' as 'decadence' is accurate.

Translate "the 贾 family's decline" as "贾家的衰落" is a correct translation.

- 衰落: decline/ descend from a high status or position
- 衰退: decline/ recede from the front or forward position
- 減弱: decline/ weakening in strength
- 減少: decline/ decrease in number or amount